# Load data to highchart using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, highcharts

I'm loading a highchart graph using following function.

```
function reloadSubGraph(data){
$(function () {
    $('#SubPatternContainer').highcharts({

        plotOptions: {
            events: {
                update: function (event) {
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Selected Pattern'
        },
        series:[{data:[[1,200],[2,200],[3,200]]}]
    });
});
```

}

It works fine, but when using ajax call to load data as follows for same data string `[{data:[[1,200],[2,200],[3,200]]}]` as follows it doesn't show on graph.

```
function getSubPatternData(patternId,patternName){
$.ajax({
    url: "/arcane/patternData1?patternId="+patternId+"&patternName="+patternName,
    type: "get",
    cache: false,

    success: function(data) {
        var tempdata=String(data);
        reloadSubGraph(tempdata);
    },
    error:function(xhr, status, error){
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

}

Can anyone point me where i'm doing wrong here. when I see the returned results of ajax using alert(data) it shows the same string that i used in reloadSubGraph() function (`[{data:[[1,200],[2,200],[3,200]]}]`)

when using with ajax i changed reloadSubGraph() funcion as follows.

```
function reloadSubGraph(data){
alert(data);
$(function () {<!--from w  w  w .j  ava 2 s  .  c  o m-->

    $('#SubPatternContainer').highcharts({

        plotOptions: {
            events: {
                update: function (event) {
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Selected Pattern'
        },
        series:data
    });
});
```

}

Comment: did you check the console. Is there any error showing ?

Comment: `var tempdata=String(data);` - I'm not sure whether the `String` should be there. Try `var tempdata = data;`

Comment: Using string is the problem here. ajax call returns a string, but highchart is not accepting string. what is the data type that i need to convert my data variable. please have a look at this for highchart data types. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series

Comment: I would advice to read about `jQuery.getJSON()` method which load JSON already. Then check your JSON if is proper one (there are on-line validators for it). In short, JSON should have names in double quotes: `data` -> `"data"`.